# LINQ Expression optimization

Tags: c#, linq

I have the code below, my goal is to get random result set with a quantity of 10 Integer lists where each list contains 4 ints whose addition to each other exceeds 80.

```
        var numList = new List<int> { 5, 20, 1, 7, 19, 3, 15, 60, 3, 21, 57, 9 };

        var extractedList = (from n1 in numList
                             from n2 in numList
                             from n3 in numList
                             from n4 in numList
                             where n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 > 80
                             select new { n1, n2, n3, n4 }).ToList();
```

Now I know I could easily add ".GetRange(startIndex, 10)" to ".ToList()" but in this scenario the extracted list will have 8799 items, will adding "GetRange" mean that only 10 items are loaded into memory, or will it mean that the 8799 gets loaded first and then filtered down to 10, I'm a LINQ newbie so I'm hoping there's an efficient way of doing this, also since I know that no number will exceed 200, would using an 8 Bit byte help with performance, any suggestions on this would be great.

Comment: The `ToList` will create a list with all items, then you will take ten from it and create a list from these. Note that you crate repetitions like `21,21,21,21` or `20,21,20,21` or `19,20,21,57` or `57,22,20,19`.

Comment: `int` is often the most efficient type to work with in .net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you want to keep using LINQ:

```
var numList = new List<int> { 5, 20, 1, 7, 19, 3, 15, 60, 3, 21, 57, 9 };

Random rnd = new Random();
var extractedList = (from n1 in numList
                     from n2 in numList
                     from n3 in numList
                     from n4 in numList
                     where n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 > 80
                     select new
                     {
                         n1,
                         n2,
                         n3,
                         n4,
                         Rnd = rnd.NextDouble()
                     })
                     .OrderBy(z => z.Rnd)
                     .Take(10)
                     .ToList();
```

Do note I've added a random parameter so you don't get always same results.

Comment: Won't the OrderBy clause enumerate the entire collection in order to order it?

Answer (score 3):

If you only want the first 10 items you can use:

var numList = new List { 5, 20, 1, 7, 19, 3, 15, 60, 3, 21, 57, 9 };

```
    var extractedList = (from n1 in numList
                         from n2 in numList
                         from n3 in numList
                         from n4 in numList
                         where n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 > 80
                         select new { n1, n2, n3, n4 }).Take(10).ToList();
```

However, it will always yield the same 10 items.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Take` method to load only specific number of items instead of all of them, then call `ToList`

```
(from n1 in numList
 from n2 in numList
 from n3 in numList
 from n4 in numList
 where n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 > 80
 select new { n1, n2, n3, n4 }).Take(10).ToList();
```

As already noted in comments this will always give the same result.You could randomize your list and then perform the query (instead of sorting thousands of combinations)

```
Random rnd = new Random();
numList = numList.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
(from n1 in numList
 from n2 in numList
 from n3 in numList
 from n4 in numList
 where n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 > 80
 select new { n1, n2, n3, n4 }).Take(10).ToList();
```

Comment: Note that this will always yield the first 10 items; so numList should be randomized. Also it will favor items to the front of the list.

Answer (score 1):

If you call .GetRange on a List, you got to have a List first.
So the entire query will be enumerated and the results will be in a list and THEN you take 10 items from that List.

If you only want those 10 items and nothing more, you can use Skip and Take on the query itself.

```
var extractedList = (from n1 in numList
                     from n2 in numList
                     from n3 in numList
                     from n4 in numList
                     where n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 > 80
                     select new { n1, n2, n3, n4 })
                     .Skip(startIndex).Take(10);
```

However, if you want to split the results into parts of length 10, than this will enumerate the entire query each time, so you don't want that. In that case storing the entire result in a List (like you're doing in your example) will be better.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Take` LINQ expression

```
var numList = new List<int> { 5, 20, 1, 7, 19, 3, 15, 60, 3, 21, 57, 9 };

    var extractedList = (from n1 in numList
                         from n2 in numList
                         from n3 in numList
                         from n4 in numList
                         where n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 > 80
                         select new { n1, n2, n3, n4 }).Take(10).ToList();
```

Which will only take the first 10 results that pass your selection criteria. To get that selection from a randomized collection, OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()) would help, but that would order the whole collection, so it depends on whether you can randomize the collection without affecting performance or not (e.g. in the background).

Alternatively you might consider writing your own extension of IList such as:

```
IList<T> GetRandomElements(this IList<T> me, int numElements)
{
    var copyOfMe = new List<T>(me);
    List<T> results = new List<T>();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for(int i=0; i<numElements;i++)
    {
        if(copyOfMe.Count > 0)
        {
            int index = Random.Next(0,results.Count);
            results.Add(copyOfMe[index]);
            copyOfMe.Remove(index);
        }
    }
}
```

But that does require an IList input (for indexing).

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with the other solutions posted here are that they are **O(n<sup>4</sup>)** since they generate all possible combinations of four items from the list before they do the filtering. That might be fine for the short list given in the question, but won't scale.

For example, defining `var numList = Enumerable.Range(10, 50).ToList();` (so there are 50 items in the list) causes other solutions here to take approximately 15 seconds; the more efficient version below takes a fraction of a second.

The trick is to define a generator function that Linq will only call the minimum number of times it needs to fulfil the query (although the `while (true)` makes it look like an infinite loop, the `yield return` causes it to return the values one at a time):

```
static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int, int, int>> Generate(IList<int> list)
{
    int max = list.Count;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new Tuple<int, int, int, int>(
            rnd.Next(max), rnd.Next(max), rnd.Next(max), rnd.Next(max));
    }
}
```

Then you can use Linq to call it, something like this:

```
var quickList = Generate(numList)
    .Where(t => t.Item1 + t.Item2 + t.Item3 + t.Item4 > 80)
    .Distinct().Take(10).ToList();
```